# Assert partial text

Tags: java, excel, xpath

I'm working on java webdriver using testNG/eclipse

I'm using excel to import data in scripts.

I have an element on webpage which has xpath 
`By.xpath("//h2[contains(.,'Projects›main›tests›Plan visit')]`

The second and third text i.e `main` and `tests` changes for different users, So in excel I have mentioned only one column, let's say 'value1', which contains 'Plan visit' as its value so it will assert for all users.

I need to first get text of this xpath in some variable let's say 'value2' then assert 'value1' with 'value2'.

Here problem is that I'm unable to get locator of only 'Plan visit'. So I want my script to assert partial text.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

```
Assert.assertTrue(value2.contains(value1),"Failure message")
```

or if you want to be a little more specific

```
Assert.assertTrue(value2.matches("Projects.*Plan visit"),"Failure message")
```

You can read up various methods [available](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html)